# How to restart Application in android from fragment

Tags: java

Below is something I want to achieve
I have fragment how to restart the entire application from That  fragment , and it should not come back to that particular fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the Below Method from where you want to restart

```
private void restartSelf() {   
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)   getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 500, // one second   
            PendingIntent.getActivity(getActivity(), 0, getActivity().getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));  
    Intent i = getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getActivity().getBaseContext().getPackageName());  
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);  
    startActivity(i);  
}
```

Comment: probably calling finish() first and then this method